# React hooks with switch-case render

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I have a component renders other ones by switch-case

```
export default function Fragment(props) {
    switch (props.type) {
        
        case FRAGMENT_TYPES.Start:
            return StartFragment(props);

        case FRAGMENT_TYPES.Rules:
            return RulesFragment(props);

        // some other cases
        
        default:    
            return null;
    } 
}
```

But I get 'order of Hooks error' if `StartFragment` uses hooks but `RulesFragment` doesn't.

How can I avoid this error? Should I raise all hooks up in `Fragment` or there is another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you call the function directly

```
Fragment(props)
```

instead of the component

```
<Fragment {...props}/>
```

`Fragment` also calls `StartFragment` and `RulesFragment` directly. So `StartFragment` and `RulesFragment` are then executed in the calling components context. Thus if `StartFragment` has a hook but `RulesFragment` don't, it's just like using hooks in conditionals. E.g.

```
const App = (props) => {
  const fragment = Fragment(props)
  ....
}
```

`App` calls function `Fragment` calls function `StartFragment`.

But when you use a component

```
const App = (props) => {
  const fragment = <Fragment {...props}/>
  ....
}
```

The `App` doesn't call the function `Fragment` directly. It calls a React component that has an own state management and this component calls the function `Fragment`. You can see it when you look at the transpiled code. It should look something like this:

```
React.createElement(Fragment, props, null);
```

That's why `<Fragment {...props}>` works but `Fragment(props)` don't.

If this is the case I would recommend to change the `Fragment` function to:

```
function Fragment(props) {
  switch (props.type) {
    case "Start":
      return <StartFragment {...props}/>;

    case "Rules":
      return <RulesFragment {...props}/>;

    // some other cases

    default:
      return <></>;
  }
}
```